# Missing Methods and Classes in Jar after Building Xamarin App

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As i wanted to develop an App with Estimote Beacons i searched for it and found the Xamarin Component [Estimote SDK for Android](https://components.xamarin.com/view/estimotesdkandroid). However, the Version is outdated so i began to try including the estimote sdk for android on myself. With [.aar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/)/[.jar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/) Binding.
I saw three Options:

- fully compile the library and be able to use it as C# Classes
- write a wrapper and only let the wrapper interpret and use those classes.
- natively call functions from the Library with JNI

Compiling the whole library did not work due to about 102 Errors while building. Working with metadata.xml did not work although i was able to reduce the amount of Errors to 45.
Natively calling functions with JNI is a pain and no option because the Library is too big.

### Writing a wrapper nearly worked

I stripped the classes from the estimotesdk.aar so i have only the classes.jar from the inside.
Wrote a Library as wrapper and put that in another jar:

- EstimoteSDK.jar --> ReferenceJar
- EstimoteWrapper --> EmbeddedJar

I can build the ClassLibrary Project in Visual Studio without Problems. I can even use the classes from the Wrapper in C#.
But now my Problem is:

### MissingMethodException and NoClassDefFoundError during Runtime

I found out the following:
The EstimoteSDK.jar and its Class-Files change after building .
For some reason, the EstimoteSDK.jar is not only copied but also modified and loses some functions and even classes.
Proof (used dex2jar tool to get the jar out of the .dex in the builded apk): 
[image: The right class File contains less functions than the right]
The right class File contains less functions than the right

### Now my Question:

how can i prevent Xamarin or any other Component from touching the EstimoteSDK.jar and stripping functions and classes from it ?

---

Setup:

- Visual Studio 2015 Professional
- Xamarin.Forms 2.0
- Windows 7
- Android and iOS-App

Comment: I would recommend working through the binding rather than doing your own JNI interop. I wrote a general guide on this that might help in some areas. https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb This doc is now in the Xamarin Android binding troubleshooting: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/ With that said, use `LibraryProjectZip` for the `.aar` and use `Metadata.xml` transformations to accomplish the binding. One note is to `remove-node` of anything that you will not use in the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after posting my question to [xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/215819#Comment_215819) where someone provided a updated version of estimotesdk ( i did not try that so far) and trying out everything i could imagine i found a solution for me:

I have two Jars (EstimoteSDK and my own written Wrapper). Including them with the correct Build Action did it for me:

---

- EstimoteSDK.jar --> **EmbeddedReferenceJar**
- List item --> EmbeddedJar

[image: All other files in this Project were not touched by me]

---

So this is the correct way to include a native library which is accessed by a wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

The magic word could be **LinkerPleaseInclude.cs**. Add a class that references the class / calls the function. But I don't know if your wrapper is in the way, because you aren't binding the estimote lib in the usual way.

```cs
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(Beaconmanager manager)
    {
        manager.RegionExitExpiration = 0L;
    }
}
```

btw: there is a crossplatform abstraction for estimote: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Estimotes.Xplat/. But it might use the outdated version you mentioned.

Edit:

**metadata.xml for Estimote**

```xml
<metadata>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.okhttp_v2_2_0.com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http']"></remove-node>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.gson_v2_3_1.com.google.gson.internal.bind']"></remove-node>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.gson_v2_3_1.com.google.gson.internal']"></remove-node>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.gson_v2_3_1.com.google.gson']"></remove-node>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.okio_v1_3_0.okio']"></remove-node>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.repackaged.maven_v3_3_3']"></remove-node>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.connection.internal.protocols']"></remove-node>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.connection.settings']/class[@name='Version']/method[@name='compareTo' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.estimote.sdk.connection.settings.Version']]/parameter[1]"
        name="type">Java.Lang.Object</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.cloud.internal']/class[@name='ChallengeResponse']/field[@name='challengeResponse']" name="name">ChallangeResponseString</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.cloud.model.google']/class[@name='Beacons']/field[@name='beacons']" name="name">BeaconList</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.estimote.sdk.cloud.model.google']/class[@name='Observations']/field[@name='observations']" name="name">ObservationList</attr>
</metadata>
```

Comment: I could do that if this class would be interpreted. But interpreting gives me lot of errors so i just added it as ReferenceJar.
From the official Documentation:
_Specifies a reference .JAR: a reference .JAR is a .JAR that one of your bound .JAR or .AAR files depends on. This reference .JAR is used only to satisfy compile-time dependencies. When you use this build action, C# bindings are not created for the reference .JAR and it is not embedded in the resulting Bindings Library .DLL._
And i can access some of the Classes so I know it is inside the .apk
And yes, its also outdated, thanks.

Comment: I'll have a look at the binding in the afternoon.

Comment: I uploaded a sample App (that doesnt work because of the exception in runtime) on my dropbox:
[App1.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/216qa2gpywi078z/App1.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Could you try to create a new Estimote sdk binding with the given metadata?

Comment: Still throws Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError... But fortunately I found another solution (marked as answer)